# How to reset state of handleReducer function?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, use-effect

I want to a clear the state depending on, when another state is changing. useEffect is perfect for this case. But I don`t know, how to clear the state. I want to clear 2 states. I am very new to programming, thats why I have no idea to do it. I consoled something, but to clear the states, its very difficult to me. The problem is also its getting more and more complexed.

````
 const initialState = {
     personalty: personalty.personaltyfields,
     contact: contact.contactfields
  }

const handleReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "Checkbox":
        state[action.index].options[action.innerIndex].value = !state[action.index].options[action.innerIndex].value;
        return [...state];
      case "Slider":
        state[action.index].options[action.innerIndex].value = action.newSliderValue;
        return [...state];
      case "Rating":
          state[action.index].options[action.innerIndex].value = action.newRatingValue;
          return [...state];
      case "TextField":
        state[action.index].options[action.innerIndex].value =  action.newTextValue;
        return [...state];
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };

 const Form = (props)  => {
 
    const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = useState(0);
    const [jobData, dispatchjobData] = useReducer(handleReducer, props.job);
    const [personaltyData, dispatchPersonaltyData] = useReducer(handleReducer,initialState.personalty);
    const [contactData, dispatchcontactData] = useReducer(handleReducer, initialState.personalty);

    const handleNext = () =>{
      setActiveStep(prevActiveStep => prevActiveStep + 1);
    };

    const handleBack = () => {
      setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep - 1);
    };

    const handleChange = useCallback(
      (index, innerIndex, type, value, newSliderValue, newRatingValue, newTextValue) => {
        switch (activeStep) {
          case 0:
            dispatchjobData({index, innerIndex,type, value, newSliderValue, newRatingValue, newTextValue});
            break;
          case 1:
            dispatchPersonaltyData({index, innerIndex, type, value, newSliderValue, newRatingValue,  newTextValue});
            break;
          case 2:
            dispatchcontactData({ index, innerIndex, type, value, newSliderValue, newRatingValue,  newTextValue});
            break;
          default:
            return null;
        }
      },
      [activeStep]
    );

    useEffect (()=>{
     dispatchPersonaltyData( {    
type:[yourtype]
payload: initialState.personalty
});
}, [props.job])```
````

Comment: Hello, if you're new to programming, you might find this post useful for helping to narrow down the problem into something easier to debug: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable, called "initialState", and let it hold  all thee state's default values, so when u want to clear the state, dispatch the action with a  initialState payload
like:

```
dispatchPersonaltyData(
 {
  type: [YOUR TYPE]. 
  payload: [VARIABLE_WITH_INITIAL_VALUES_FOR_PERSONALITY_DATA]
 }
)
```

Comment: I didnt unterstand, what is meant by type. For every action.type a type?

Answer (score 0):

I added the initial State:
 `const initialPersonality = personalty.personaltyfields;`

I expanded handleReducer:
 `case "clearState": return action.payload;`

I cloned my Object, with the npm function cloneDeep.

````
      dispatchPersonaltyData({
        type: "clearState",
        payload : cloneDeep(initialPersonality)
      })
    }, [props.job]);```
````